# problem with word breakers in full-text search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a full-text catalog and I use full text index on some of the columns in a table. The problem is, if I try to change the language for word breaker in the properties of my full text catalog to my national language (polish) ft searching does not work (the query returns no rows). English and neutral word breakers works fine, but polish would be more suitable for the data I have. I've read and followed steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345188.aspx) but it didn't solve the problem. The similar problem also occured in sql server 2008 (not r2) and there was a [hotfix solving it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980350) but it doesn't work with r2 from what I've read. If anyone knows a way to to enable polish word breakers I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you provide http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980350, this is mentioned as being fixed for R2 in cumulative update 6.

Comment: yes i actualy have been updated a while ago and it works, forgot to update the topic, thanks for looking into it